# How to use array values as keys without loops?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

Looping is time consuming, we all know that. That's exactly something I'm  trying to avoid, even though it's on a small scale. Every bit helps. Well, if it's unset of course :)

#### On to the issue

I've got an array:

```
array(3) {
    '0' => array(2) {
        'id'   => 1234,
        'name' => 'blablabla',
    },
    '1' => array(2) {
        'id'   => 1235,
        'name' => 'ababkjkj',
    },
    '2' => array(2) {
        'id'   => 1236,
        'name' => 'xyzxyzxyz',
    },
}
```

What I'm trying to do is to convert this array as follows:

```
array(3) {
    '1234' => 'blablabla',
    '1235' => 'asdkjrker',
    '1236' => 'xyzxyzxyz',
}
```

I guess this aint a hard thing to do but my mind is busted right now and I can't think of anything except for looping to get this done.

Comment: A foreach isn't exactly a loop - it will iterate through the array ONCE. If you get your output array to be what it needs to be on each pass (which seems trivial given your requirements) it doesn't seem a "waste of resources" at all.

Comment: Either you write the loop, or you call a sexy php function that will do the looping for you.

Comment: I don't think you can't avoid a cycle: logically , you must check each element => you need to go from the start to the end of the array. in C/C++ you probably could move the pointer by a specific offset, but i don't think you can apply something similar here

Comment: I have to say more: don't try to avoid looping! Plain for looping is the fastest solution. Look at my [benchmarks](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31202835/how-to-set-an-array-value-as-array-key-without-looping/31203043#31203043).

Comment: So you want us to do benchmarking?

Comment: I've already done benchmarks for almost all offered solutions in my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31202835/how-to-set-an-array-value-as-array-key-without-looping/31203043#31203043).

Comment: @Ostrovski: sorry the comment was for OP. The question looks too broad to me.

Comment: Looping is time consuming *while coding*.

Comment: @Peter you had an open bounty what is your expected array

Comment: Loop unrolling will help you to reduce the number of comparison if you can make it work (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop_unrolling).

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Simply use `array_combine` along with the `array_column` as

```
array_combine(array_column($array,'id'), array_column($array,'name'));
```

Or you can simply use `array_walk` if you have PHP < 5.5 as

```
$result = array();
array_walk($array, function($v)use(&$result) {
    $result[$v['id']] = $v['name']; 
});
```

**Edited:**

For future user who has PHP > 5.5 can simply use `array_column` as

```
array_column($array,'name','id');
```

[**Fiddle(array_walk)**](https://eval.in/391641)

Comment: Though this is quite an old question, I just stumbled over it. Simply `array_column($input, 'name', 'id')` will produce the same output (reference: [`index_key`](https://php.net/manual/function.array-column.php)).

Comment: `array_walk` is still a loop at heart it's an iterator the same as a `for` (you define the iteration system based on integer) or `foreach` (it's a basic key to value iteration system one at a time iteration), however the other methods use iterators it's just how much of it do you want Compiled code compared to scripted code :)

Answer (score 8):

**UPD**: **Warning** the slowest solution! See benchmarks below.

Try this code:

```
$a = array(array('id'   => 1234,
                 'name' => 'blablabla'),
           array('id'   => 1235,
                 'name' => 'ababkjkj'),
           array('id'   => 1236, 
                 'name' => 'xyzxyzxyz'));

var_export(array_reduce($a, function($res, $item) {
    $res[$item['id']] = $item['name'];
    return $res;
}));
```

Works fine even in PHP 5.3. And uses only one function `array_reduce`.

**UPD:**
Here are some benchmarks (PHP 5.6 over Debian 7 on a medium quality server):

```
$a = [];
for ($i = 0; $i < 150000; $i++) {
    $a[$i] = ['id' => $i,
               'name' => str_shuffle('abcde') . str_shuffle('01234')];
}

$start = microtime(true);

if (false) {
    // 7.7489550113678 secs for 15 000 itmes
    $r = array_reduce($a, function($res, $item) {
             $res[$item['id']] = $item['name'];
             return $res;
         });
}

if (false) {
    // 0.096649885177612 secs for 150 000 items
    $r = array_combine(array_column($a, 'id'),
                       array_column($a, 'name'));
}

if (true) {
    // 0.066264867782593 secs for 150 000 items
    $r = [];
    foreach ($a as $subarray) {
        $r[$subarray['id']] = $subarray['name'];
    }
}

if (false) {
    // 0.32427287101746 secs for 150 000 items
    $r = [];
    array_walk($a, function($v) use (&$r) {
        $r[$v['id']] = $v['name'];
    });
}

echo (microtime(true) - $start)  . ' secs' . PHP_EOL;
```

**So, as a conclusion:** *plain iteration* with simple `for` loop is a **winner** (as mentioned in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31202835/how-to-set-an-array-value-as-array-key-without-looping/31203043#31203662)). On a second place there is `array_combine` allowed only for new versions of PHP. And the worst case is using my own solution with closure and `array_reduce`.

Comment: Why do you use array_reduce instead of array_map ?

Comment: By semantic reasons. You have an array as the input and you want to obtain single element on the output. Despite of it is array of arrays on the input and just and array on the output.

Comment: @OIS `array_map` can transform the values, but not the keys. If we tried, we'd get something like `[0 => 'blablabla', 1 => 'asdkjrker', 2 => 'xyzxyzxyz']`. We *could* build up the result as a side-effect, eg. `array_map(function($val) use (&result) { $result[$val['id']] = $val['name']; }, $input)` but iteratively building up values is exactly what `array_reduce` is for :)

Answer (score 7):

If you have php >= 5.5:

```
$res = array_combine(array_column($source, 'id'), array_column($source, 'name'));
```

If not - make a loop.

Comment: Its sexy, but something somewhere is doing the looping

Comment: Huh, how can you avoid looping even on the background? I think question is about avoiding looping in the user space.

Comment: Potentially this will be 3 loops instead of one! if you actually think about it. Admittedly it will be a piece of `C` code doing the looping but do 3x`c` loops run faster than 1x`php` loops

Comment: @RiggsFolly no, array function loops are slower than php language construct foreach. 3 array functions even more so.

Comment: @OIS I ment that using `array_combine()` with 2 `array_column()` functions would cause 3 loops even though they are `C` based. Doing it yourself in PHP would only be one.

Comment: But PHP loops very slow, using build in functions to let a more efficient language take care of it, is 9 out of 10 times a lot faster

Answer (score 4):

Make use of [**array_map**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) function, (PHP 4 >= 4.0.6, PHP 5)

```
[akshay@localhost tmp]$ cat test.php
<?php

$array = array(
                array('id'   => 1234,'name' => 'blablabla'),
                array('id'   => 1235,'name' => 'ababkjkj'),
                array('id'   => 1236,'name' => 'xyzxyzxyz')
              );

$output = array();
array_map(function($_) use (&$output){ $output[$_['id']] = $_['name']; },$array);

// Input
print_r($array);

// Output
print_r($output);

?>
```

**Output**

```
[akshay@localhost tmp]$ php test.php
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1234
            [name] => blablabla
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1235
            [name] => ababkjkj
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1236
            [name] => xyzxyzxyz
        )

)
Array
(
    [1234] => blablabla
    [1235] => ababkjkj
    [1236] => xyzxyzxyz
)
```

Comment: why down vote  ? whats wrong ? please let me know the reason

Comment: This solution is abusing the purpose of `array_map`, which could cause confusion and hence bugs. `array_map` is meant to create `[f(a), f(b), f(c)]` from `f` and `[a, b, c]`, in a way which avoids cross-iteration interference and having to manage the order of evaluation. Here we're ignoring the result, we have cross-iteration interference (updating the same `$output`), and we must take the order of evaluation into account (eg. for duplicate IDs). The purpose of `array_reduce` matches this problem more closely: building a result iteratively in a specified order.

Comment: I disagree with what you said but anyways thanks for the time you spent for comment.

Answer (score 3):

This is the fastest and simplest code here so far ...

```
$result = [];
foreach ($input as $subarray) {
    $result[$subarray["id"]] = $subarray["name"];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this function:

```
array_combine(array_column($array,'id'), array_column($array,'name'));
```