# PHP array replace numbers with keys

Tags: php, arrays

I have this array...

```
Array
(
    [result] => Success
    [finals] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 633
                    [name] => RESULT84
                )
                [0] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 766
                    [name] => RESULT2
                )
                [0] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 22
                    [name] => RESULT1
                )
        )
)
```

And I am extracting the names like this...

```
$names = array_column($data['finals'], 'name');
print_r($names);
```

Which gives me...

```
Array
(
    [0] => RESULT84
    [1] => RESULT2
    [2] => RESULT1
)
```

My question is how can I modify it so that I get this...

```
Array
(
    [RESULT84] => RESULT84
    [RESULT2] => RESULT2
    [RESULT1] => RESULT1
)
```

Is something like array_fill_keys my best bet?

Comment: [array_combine](http://php.net/array_combine). Though it sounds off that you need keys and values with the same string...

Comment: `$names[array_column($data['finals'], 'name')] = array_column($data['finals'], 'name');` maybe

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use array values as keys without loops?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31202835/how-to-use-array-values-as-keys-without-loops)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Pass third parameter `name` into  [**`array_column`**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) to make it key

```
 $names = array_column($data['finals'], 'name','name');
 print_r($names);
```

Answer (score 2):

Saty answered it right. Here is the complete code:

```
<?php
$data = Array
    (
        'result' => 'Success',
        'finals' => Array
        (
            Array
                (
                    'id' => 633,
                    'name' => 'RESULT84'
                ),
            Array
                (
                    'id' => 766,
                    'name' => 'RESULT2'
                ),
            Array
                (
                    'id' => 22,
                    'name' => 'RESULT1'
                )
        )
    );

$names = array_column($data['finals'], 'name','name');
print_r($names);
?>
```