# How to get the value of a key based on the known value of a sibling key from a PHP associative array?

Tags: php, arrays

Consider the following array:

```
$bookmarksIDs = [
    [
        "id"=> 33767,
        "dateAdded"=> 1551944452042
    ],
    [
        "id"=> 33743,
        "dateAdded"=> 1551944540159
    ]
]
```

If I know the value of `id`, how do I get the value of its sibling `dateAdded` key?

Comment: `if($bookmarksIDs['id'] == '33767'){//you now know the dateAdded}`

Comment: Well, it's the same way how you cast the `id`.

Answer (score 2):

you can do something like:

```
foreach ($bookmarksIDs as $bookmarksID) {
    if($bookmarksID["id"] == "33767"){
        //do something
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the value of the sibling you need to iterate over the array to find it as @MRustamzade answered.

```
 foreach ($bookmarksIDs as $bookmarksID) {
  if($bookmarksID["id"] == "33767"){
    //do something
   }
 }
```

But if you are seeking for better performance you may change the structure of the array to be indexed by id value ie:

```
$bookmarksIDs = [
"id_33767"=>[

    "dateAdded"=> 1551944452042
],
"id_33743"=>[
    "dateAdded"=> 1551944540159
]
]
```

so you can access it directly by:

```
 $bookmarksIDs["id_".$id/*33743*/]["dateAdded"];
```

In this case make sure that the value of id is unique to not override the old values

**Or you can use if you want to preserve the array structure**

```
  array_column($bookmarksIDs ,'dateAdded','id')
```

to get array like :

```
 $bookmarksIDs = [
 "33767"=>1551944452042  
 , 
 "33743"=> 1551944540159

]
```

And the dateAdded it directly bookmarksIDs["33767"].

Comment: You can achieve this with: `$bookmarksIDs = array_combine(array_column($bookmarksIDs, "id"), $bookmarksIDs);`

Comment: +1 this is a way to create the indexed array but if initially the array is created in the right format it will resut in better performance, as array_combine will result in iteration over the arrray, anyway this deppends on what @grazianodev needs

Comment: @AliAboud I like your idea! However, if I structured the array as you suggest, how could I get the `id` before I get `dateAdded`? Right now, with the array as I originally presented it in the question, I do `array_column( $bookmarksIDs, 'id' )`, but of course this won't work using your array structure... I'm not very good at arrays :)

Comment: @grazianodev check this answer to understand how array_column works  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31202835/how-to-use-array-values-as-keys-without-loops?answertab=votes#tab-top
you will be able to access you target using this line 
`$bookmarksIDs["id_".$id/*33743*/]`

Comment: I edited my answer to consider array_column solution